# Laravel eloquent join multiple tables in the leftjoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in laravel. I'm trying to join multiple tables in the left join however i facing the syntax error and i have no idea where goes wrong.

**Code**

```
$query = DB::table('sales')
    ->leftjoin('transactions AS trx', function ($join) {
        $join->on('payment_methods AS payment', 'payment.id', '=', 'trx.payment_method_id');
        $join->on('transactables', 'transactables.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
            ->whereNull('transactions.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('transactables.deleted_at')
            ->where('transactable_type', '=', 'Sale')
            ->where('transactable_id', '=', 'sales.id');
    })
```

The error meesage

```
Syntax error near '`payment_methods` as `payment` payment.id `=` and `transactions`.`deleted_at` is'
```

As the code above you can see. I'm trying to join table `payment_methods` and `transactables` within the `transactions` table.

Comment: you cannot join two table in one closure.

Comment: @TsaiKoga which mean i need to join the others two table as sub query?

Comment: `payment_methods` and `transactables` ?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes. Or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use multiple `leftjoin`, or you can call eloquent builder relationship by `with`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Eloquent like

```
$sales = Sale::with('transactions')->get();
```

Add relation in Sale model

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Transaction', 'transactable');
}
```

For more info, please refer to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)